# Differential equation $2x^4yy'+y^4 = 4x^6$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I have differential equation

### $2x^4yy'+y^4 = 4x^6$

How to find real parameter $m$ for which, when we introduce substitution $y=z^m$, given equation becomes **first order homogeneous differential equation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
2x^4y y'+y^4=4x^6\tag 1
$$
We write
$$
x^4(y^2)'+(y^2)^2=4x^6
$$
Set $w=y^2$. Hence
$$
x^4w'+w^2=4x^6\tag 2
$$
This equation has partial solution $w=-4x^3$. So we set $w=-4x^3z$ and (2) becomes
$$
x(1+3z-4z^2+xz')=0
$$
Hence
$$
z'=(4z^2-3z-1)/x
$$
or
$$
\frac{dz}{4z^2-3z-1}=\frac{dx}{x}
$$
or integrating
$$
\frac{1}{5}\log(1-z)-\frac{1}{5}\log(1+4z)=c+\log x
$$
or
$$
z=\frac{1-Ax^5}{1+4Ax^5}\textrm{, }A=const
$$
Hence
$$
w=-4x^3\frac{1-Ax^5}{1+4Ax^5}
$$
and finaly
$$
y=y(x)=2\sqrt{x^3\frac{Ax^5-1}{4x^5+1}}\textrm{, }A=const
$$

Answer (score 1):

Ans: $\frac{3}{2}$

we have,
$2x^4yy'+y^4 = 4x^6$

rearranging,
$y'=\frac{4x^6-y^4}{2x^4y}$

now
substituting $$y=z^m$$
                  $$dy=mz^{m-1}dz$$
$$z'=\frac{4x^6-z^{4m}}{mz^{2m-1}x^4}$$

Now for $m=\frac32$ equation is homogeneous.